# Peano's theory of arithmetic and Gödel's 1st Incompleteness Theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory, incompleteness

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be Peano's 1st order theory of arithmetic and $\mathscr{A}$ it's standard model (which we assume exists). Infer from Gödel's 1st Incompleteness Theorem that there exists a closed well founded formula say $B$ of $\mathcal{N}$ and a model $\mathscr{W}$ of $\mathcal{N}$, such that $B$ is ture in $\mathscr{A}$ and $B$ is false in $\mathscr{W}$. Any help is really needed and app recited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The theory is usually denoted by $\sf PA$ and the standard model by $\Bbb N$. Also, "wff" means well-formed formula, not well-founded formula.

Comment: Don't let the words "Peano" and "Gödel" impress you. Being an incomplete theory exactly means to have at least two non elementary equivalent models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a canonical Gödel G sentence for PA i.e. a wff that "says" of itself 'I am unprovable in PA'. Ask yourself:

1. Is G provable from the axioms of PA?
2. Is G true in every model of the axioms of PA?
3. Is G true at least in the standard model of PA?
4. What can you deduce from your last two answers?

Hint: for one of these answers you appeal to Gödel's *completeness* theorem for first-order logic, and the fact that PA is a first-order theory.

Comment: Picking $G$ is somewhat more specific than you really need.

Comment: Yes, more specific than is needed, but the obvious choice ...

Comment: Thanks, Peter This is my reasoning then, would appreciate if you could let me know if it is correct. From the 1st Incompleteness theorem we know we have a sentence $G$ and that $G$ is true, in $\mathbb{N}$ but not provable.

So since $G$ is not provable, $PA$ & $\neg G$ is consistent.
Therefore by Gödel's completeness theorem, there is a model $\mathscr{W}$ in which $G$ is false.  Thanks again really appreciate a great don as yourself answering my question. We used your formal Logic book in my 1st and 2nd years.

Comment: Yes indeed. Exactly! (And always good to hear that the Logic book is being used out there!)